# Can Wordpress be used to create webpages that tie into pre-existing php files and database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a website that I've developed, which includes hand-written php, html, css, and js.  I also created the MySQL database.

I've recently brought someone on who is going to make the website look better, but his experience is limitted to working with Wordpress.  I'm wondering if it makes sense for him to the the front-end "skin" work with Wordpress and for me to edit the files as needed so they submit data to my php files and connect to my database.  If the php generated by Wordpress is reasonable, this seems doable in theory.

The other way would be to take the html genrated by his php and use that as my starting point for hooking into my php processing files and database.

He sent me a dump of the files created after he created a simple webpage and there seemed to be a lot of extra stuff in there.

Can anyone with experience in this comment?  I'm hoping there's an easy way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't generate PHP - you would e.g. build templates that contain WP specific PHP code. Anyway, it's not really clear what you are trying to do. What is the problem exactly? Can you clarify?

Comment: Please just ask one question, this is like a series of questions. We can't do your work for you.

Comment: Let me try to clarify. The task is update to the look and feel of the website, but to keep the relational database (and much of the php processing code) that I've created.  Ideally this would be accomplished by modifying the existing php and css files.  However, the person tasked with the asignment doesn't have this skillset.  He works using Wordpress.  So the question is "Can Wordpress be used to create webpages that tie into an existing php/mySQL system?"

Comment: Put another way:
I have php files that generate html files that users see when they visit my website. These files have forms, which post data to my server. The files that process this data manipulate it and insert it into a MySQL database. I want to keep my files that process this data and insert it into the database. I also want to keep my database. I just want WordPress to create the page that my users see.
Is this easily supported or is WordPress not for me?

Comment: I've also posted this question at Wordpress.  I've had good luck here in the past, so thought I'd try here too.

Answer (score 1):

The default procedure for me that always worked well:

- You provide outlines/simple sketchups/your old layout, so the "designer" knows vaguely how you want it to be
- You define what the site should do ("there should be a button to...", "there should be a list of..., when you click on it..."). So he knows what happens and what site follows another. **That's important**! He must understand the site.
- The better you do the above, the better the results you get from the designer will be
- The designer generates layouts in pure HTML with CSS: Example sites with example data, where everything you said before is integrated.
- You cut up the HTML-code and integrate it yourself in your php-code

This procedure has also the benefit, that an external designer does not get in contact with your application's internal php-code (and cannot "steal" it). And you can dry up your internal code when you integrate the HTML you get.

Comment: Thank you for your well-put advice. I can appreciate that my question wasn't quite pin-pointed. I really like the designer that uses wordpress, so I think I'll try having him put his wordpress designed pages on my server, then I'll view them with a web browser and get the html that way. Then I'll do as you said and integrate my php-code. Hopefully it won't be that nasty. It would be way easier if he could work with pure HTML and CSS.  I marked your answer as helpful it made me realize I need to get his HTML, which I'll do via a web browser.